# STD Queue: Efficient, or overkill?

Tags: c++, queue

I'm parsing a financial market data feed that has lots of data.

I will receive a string and extract a value, which I will store in a globally declared variable.

The program works like this: When data (string) arrives, a thread is invoked. This thread checks a value passed alongside the string to understand what kind of string it is.

Conditioned on it being the kind of string for my interest, my question is this:

Is it better to pass the string into a queue, for parsing, or to simply parse directly within the invoked thread.

Conceptually, I am worried that if I ask the invoked thread to do work then it may not be available for subsequent market data events, which occur at high frequency, and I will lose data.

Were I to place the string in a queue, I would of course need another thread that popped items off the queue and parsed them.

I have a very fast PC and speed is my interest here. Does the board have experience and know what is the best approach here?

Comment: What do you mean by “will lose data”?  How are the messages arriving?  Wouldn't it simply delay a bit?  Also, I'm uncertain what you mean by “invoke a thread”.  *Creating* a new thread for each incoming message is not a very efficient solution.  Rather use a producer-consumer queue with a fixed number of threads.

Comment: Apology for my very poor vocabulary here. I'm new to C++. There is a void routine that is passed the string of interest and a value for the type of string it is. The declaration is: void CIBTraderDlg::tickString(TickerId tickerId, TickType tickType, const CString& value) and I will already need an IF on ticktype. So I don't know if I should just go ahead and parse the string here or push it into a queue to be parsed by a different thread.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't really help me understand what you are doing.  Would it perhaps be possible to post some reasonably small code example that gives us an idea of your setup.  Leave out all the unrelated functionality, just your current design skeleton.

Comment: By your last comment, you already appear to be using either some already existing codebase, or some existing 3rd party library. These kinds of questions entirely depend on each particular situation. There is no universal "this is the best way to do it" answer for every given situation, that's always correct, and always works with every software library, platform, operating system that's currently being used on the third plant of the Solar system. The only way to get the answer here is to try different approaches, and run some benchmarks to figure out which one produces the fastest results.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, and yes it is an API sample application that I am editing. I don't control the functionality that takes a Message requesting market data for a security whereby this routine is automatically called every time data arrives. I need to parse and use the strings. I'm a newbie to all of this and I was hoping thee was a clean "right or wrong" as to how to handle these situations when there will be a lot of data to be processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real question is, do you care more about the **latency** of your system, or about the **throughput**.

If you optimize for latency, meaning that you want to respond as soon as the event occured (which is usually the case in HFT), you'll probably try to avoid passing variables to another thread, as this will generate unnecesary slowdown and will increase your latency. In particular, while optimizing for latency, you want your CPU cache not to be invalidated, which often may be the case if you use multithreading (well, at least more often, than if it's single threaded). Besides, checking what specific string contains is **really** fast in comparison to sending things over a network, meaning that if that's the only operation you shouldn't be worried about too many messages coming in and waiting to be processed. Even if it happens, the message will gently wait in kernels queue for a microsecond, while you're processing the previous one. To put it in perspective, I'd assume that if you're getting less than 300 thousand messages per second (and I'd bet you do) and the only thing you're doing is checking if the string contains a pattern, you should not go for threads.

On the other hand, if you care more about throughput - meaning that you really have a lot messages (think hunderds of thousands per second), or you're doing more heavy computations, than just searching for a pattern in a string, then probably it's better to use queue and process events in another thread.

Comment: Thank you, for teaching me something about the threads and the kernel while answering my question to apparent perfection.

Comment: It's a privilege to get help like this almost immediately and at no cost to me. It's a gift to me and I thank you.